# How to save items of list with their index in text file using c#

Tags: c#, c#-2.0

I have created a list in c#, now I need to save the list in text file with the index for each item in the list? please explain with a simple example.

Comment: Can you provide us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: What does you list actually contain and in what format do you want to store it? (txt, json, xml).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this Code: i hope you will get the basic idea from it.

```
namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> _names = new List<string>()
            {
                "Rehan",
                "Hamza",
                "Adil",
                "Arif",
                "Hamid",
                "Hadeed"
            };

            using (StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter(@"E:\test.txt")
            {
                foreach (string line in _names)
                    outputFile.WriteLine(line);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

OR you should try for loop as well.

```
namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> _names = new List<string>()
            {
                "Rehan",
                "Hamza",
                "Adil",
                "Arif",
                "Hamid",
                "Hadeed"
            };

            using (StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter(@"E:\test.txt")
            {
                for (int index = 0; index < _names.Count; index++)
                    outputFile.WriteLine("Index : " + index + " - " + _names[index]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> **According to your Comment Below:**
>   How to save a list data into a SQL Server table. You can follow the
>   same principle from the above code:

**Code:**

```
namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Table 
            // -------------
            // | ID | Name |
            // -------------

           // Please Not that: ID Column in a database should not be identity Colomn because in this example i am going to add data to ID Column explicity...                

            // List of name that we are going to save in Database.
            List<string> _names = new List<string>()
            {
                "Rehan",
                "Hamza",
                "Adil",
                "Arif",
                "Hamid",
                "Hadeed"
            };

            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Connection string goes here...");
            connection.Open();
            for (int index = 0; index < _names.Count; index++)
            {
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tbl_names (id,name) VALUES ('"+index+"', '"+_names[index]+"')",connection);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

> **Note:** by using this syntax `new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tbl_names...` there is a Chance of SQL Injection so by avoiding that you can use Store Procedure instead....

Comment: Why use Path.Combine for simple path?

Comment: `File.WriteAllLines(path, lines.Select((value, index) => $"{index}: {value}"))` would be somewhat simpler.

Comment: thank you very much. How can I save the list save the list in SQL Server 2012 with the index for each item in the list?please explain with a simple example.

Comment: You can follow that same idea for saving list item in SQL Server Table....i am going to add a example Code at the end of my answer...please check that and get the basic idea from it.. @AfraArif